# drawInRect not preserving transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size);

    UIImageView *image1 = backgroundImageView;
    UIImageView *image2 = boat;

    // Draw image1  
    [image1.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.image.size.width, image1.image.size.height)];  

    // Draw image2  
    [image2.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(boat.center.x, boat.center.y, boat.image.size.width, boat.image.size.height)];  


    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

When resultingImage is displayed the transform angle value for image2 is not preserved after I set it equal to the boat UIImageView.  I thought that when I set image2 = boat that the transform value of boat would carry over to image2.

I suspect it relates to the fact that I am I am working with UIImageView instead of UIVIew.    I have tried many different things but have been unable to resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you draw an image into a graphics context, it uses the *context's* transformation matrix, which is distinct from any transformation applied to a view. So the transformation on `image2` (a `UIImageView` presumably) is completely irrelevant to direct image drawing.

You can either specify a new transformation with the various `CGContext` and `CGAffineTransform` functions in Quartz, or you can directly apply a *copy of* the `UIImageView` 's transformation like so:

```
CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), someView.transform);
[someView.image drawInRect: CGRectMake(...)];
```

Comment: I tired your suggestions and I ended up with mixed results.  When image2 is on the resultingImage it has the right orientation but the location is wrong sometimes not even on the screen.  I also tried the line below and similar results.                                             CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), (-M_PI/360 + atan2f(distancey, distancex)));

Comment: If you're applying a rotation, then it will rotate drawing around a virtual axis at the top left corner of the image. A view, when rotated, rotates around its midpoint by default.